# Loop optimization

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

In **C** Programming, We can enable/disable loop optimization using *#pragma* preprocessor directive.

In which scenario, **loop optimization** should turned off ?

Comment: No, in C programming there is no explicit control over optimizations and `#pragma` has implementation-defined behavior. Maybe you mean MSVC or something, and if so, you should tag your question as such...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimisation is off by default when you compile for debug (so that source code lines in the debugger exactly match the code being executed).

You would only use the pragma in very specific circumstances, such as:

- You find an optimisation limitation/bug leading to undefined behaviour ([What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) (Thanks to @R)
- You need exact real-time timing

Comment: Rather than an optimization bug, it's probably a case of your code invoking UB, if the code "seems to work" with optimization off.

Comment: I agree with @R.  Every C programmer really should read all 3 parts of [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) from the LLVM blog.